# Altium buses between sheets on a flat design

Tags: circuit-design, altium, differential, bus

I have a really big design to do and I'm having a rough time with buses. I have several doubts I hope someone can help me solve.

Can I take a bus between sheets using an **Off-Sheet Connector**? For example:

[image: Altium Bus + Off-Sheet connector]

Can I make a bus containing *differential pairs*? (And take it to another sheet using an Off-Sheet Connector)
I have tons of differential pairs and I'd like to avoid using so many individuals **Off-Sheet Connectors**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use harnesses instead of busses to pass them between sheets in a hierarchical design:

[image]

[image]
Source: [EEvblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/altium/how-do-i-include-a-differential-pair-line-in-a-bus-structure/)

You will get compiler warnings which you can [turn off if you so desire](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((Compiling+and+Verifying+the+Design))_AD#!CompilingandVerifyingtheDesign-ResolvingaWarningorError)

Comment: That should solve my problem with differential pairs. What about buses and Off-Sheet connectors?

Comment: The harness can use busses and connectors to pass between sheets in a hierarchical design. In theory harneses should be able to work with offsheet connectors as they simply define a bus, but I have not tested this.

Comment: I have tested the busses and it works, I never use off sheet connectors.